# Open iOS app from URL AND Pass Parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, parameters, url-scheme

A link should open the app. I've got that to work. I just want to know how to pass a parameter. Let's say the url is "addappt://?code=abc". When a view controller pops up, a code field should have populated text - the letters after the equals to sign. I've got part of this to work. I use the following  `(in app delegate.m)`:

```
NSArray *elements = [url.query componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *key = [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          val = [[elements objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(BTW: val is declared in appdelegate.h

I am also able to pass `val` to the view controller. My only problem is populating the textfield, named `'code'`. How can you populate code as soon as the app is opened by the link?

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Don't need to. I just need `code` populated

Comment: I know how to populate it, just need to know what method

Comment: In AppDelegate, have "viewController.code setText:val;", assuming that code is a text field and is available as a property of the viewController.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial on [Using Custom URL Scheme in iOS](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

As in the tutorial, you should parse the URL parameters and store them to use in the app in this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  // Do something with the url here
}
```

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar Sorry for that. Thanks for pointing it out. It should work fine now.

Comment: is it possible to make such URL which will send the user to Appstore if the app is not installed.

Comment: Apple recommends to implement the method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`  to handle custom urls.

Comment: Swift 3, XCode 8, the method is:
`func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [String : AnyObject] = [:]) -> Bool`
Cheers

Comment: but by hitting the url in mail it cannot open because that url convert like this chatapp/

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 12 this code works perfectly. You can imagine that this is also a URL as regular. In Source app you can call and open destination url with parameter like

```
    let url = URL(string: "DestinationApp:PATH?PARAMETER=11111")
           
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!) { (result) in
        if result {
            print(result)
           // The URL was delivered successfully!
        }
    }
```

Destination app can handle metod in AppDelegate with this method. Alert is for double check.

```
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
            // Determine who sent the URL.
            let sendingAppID = options[.sourceApplication]
            print("source application = \(sendingAppID ?? "Unknown")")
    
            // Process the URL.
            guard let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
                let path = components.path,
                let params = components.queryItems else {
                    print("Invalid URL or path missing")
                    return false
            }
    
            if let parameter = params.first(where: { $0.name == "PARAMETER" })?.value {
                print("path = \(path)")
                print("parameter = \(parameter)")
    
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Path = \(path)", message: "Parameter = \(parameter)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
                let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    
                if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                    while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                        topController = presentedViewController
                    }
    
                    topController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                return true
            } else {
                print("parameter is missing")
                return false
            }
}
```