# How to create a link that will open an app and a web view on top of the app page?

Tags: android, ios, webview, deep-linking

The case is the following:
User receives a push notification and tap on it.
Link lands user on the app that sent notification and opens a webview on top of the app. It doesn't mater whether the user sees that app is opened but it is important to keep the app opened when user closes the webview page.

I am doing it because the app that i am working with does have an integration with a mobile ad platform, other views I will set a full screen banner.

Is it possible to set a link that does two things: open an app and trigger the webview? Are there any other solutions for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use an Intent. See this [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

You can open an Activity inside your app that contains the webview.

For iOS you can use a custom URL scheme, see this [Open iOS app from URL AND Pass Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227288/open-ios-app-from-url-and-pass-parameters)

You can use the parameters to open a ViewController that has the webview.