# open url with your app and pass params

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing two versions of app(android, and ios)
In android when i open url from email the system gives me several options of opening it: browser, my app.

I can open the url(http://www.someurl/path?param1=2&param2=1) with my application and get the params. Is there a way to do it in ios? thanks in advance

Comment: yes, there is. did you google it?

Comment: ye, i did. But i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227288/open-ios-app-from-url-and-pass-parameters 
I'm not sure it meets my needs, because url is addappt://?code=abc, not http://

Comment: @Wain can you give me some link how to do it the right way, because what i saw on google differs from each others

Comment: Tolle lege: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW21

Comment: @matt ye, thanks,  but how to tell the system so it will register your app as the app which can open specific URI?

Comment: @JenyaKyrmyza Okay: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10

Comment: @matt cool, it's what i needed

Comment: Did you solve this issue as I'm trying to do the same