# How to open an application from iOS device when a link shared from a web app is clicked?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I have used branch.io deeplinking for sharing from mobile.I have a web app also for the same mobile application which uses another method for sharing.
I would like to open my application from iOS device, when a link shared from web app is clicked from mobile.
I can successfully redirect to a web app page when a link shared from mobile is clicked from desktop.
Please help.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227288/open-ios-app-from-url-and-pass-parameters)

Comment: If that doesn't suit your need, just inform then we can help you.

Comment: Follow https://blog.mixpanel.com/2015/04/21/guide-setting-up-deep-linking-in-ios-and-android/ for Mobile Side

Comment: you can also use Universal Links

Comment: @NikhilManapure Isn't URL scheme deprecated from iOS 9.3?

Comment: @PiyushRathi I guess you have provided another third party service.I would like to do with branch.io setup.Thanks.

Comment: @akhiljij This is not third party procedure, it is for mobile side. For deep Linking some setting must be done on device like set up URLScheme, and on your web page header you need to include some tags so that when you click on that this will redirect to your app and With Scheme it opens ur mobile app.

Comment: @PiyushRathi It somehow shows "deliver through mixpanel" . Is there any option I can achieve it without any third party involvement.?

Comment: @akhiljij yes you can do it. First for mobile Side set URL scheme

Comment: @PiyushRathi I have set URL scheme for my application.

Comment: @akhiljij have you tested it with browser? as it is working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130576/discussion-between-piyushrathi-and-akhiljij).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: to make this work, the sharing links from your web app should also be Branch links. This is what will let your mobile app open if a link is clicked on a mobile device. You can think of Branch as a router that takes incoming visitors and forwards them on to the appropriate destination depending on what device type they are using.

[image]

The [Branch web SDK](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking) makes this extremely easy to implement. You should be able to use that as a drop-in replacement for whatever existing sharing method you currently use.

Comment: How to make the iOS device identify the link shared from web should open the ios application?

Comment: There are a number of ways this is done, mainly via Universal Links and occasionally via URI schemes. If you have completed the [Branch onboarding steps](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/), this should all be taken care of for you.